Tesseract ocr - problems finding languages
I was having problems with Ubuntu 22.04 on my Framework laptop, and did a complete re-installation, using Ubuntu 24.04.1.  I have just reinstalled Tesseract using snap.  It was was working ok previously on Ubuntu 22.04, but now gives the error:
Error opening data file /snap/tesseract/current/usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.

I tried to install English as follows:
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng

which was apparently successful, but using:
tesseract --list-langs

I got the following response:
List of available languages in "/snap/tesseract/current/usr/local/share/tessdata/" (0):

and trying to translate something gave the same error as above.
I have tried searching for this problem without success.  Any ideas?
Many thanks, Andrew

Why are you installing the snap version of tesseract while the language package is installed through apt?

because I don't understand snap and apt!  I didn't realise they were both oranges: I thought apt was a command and snap was a place to get software, i.e. oranges and apples...
...I would be grateful for full clarification of my confusion!

If I were you, I would just install the apt version of tesseract and not the snap version:
$ sudo snap remove tesseract
$ sudo apt install tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng

After the above commands, you should have the following:
$ type tesseract
tesseract is /usr/bin/tesseract

If not, you may have to log out and then log back in and / or check your $PATH environment variable.
Also, the command
$ snap list | grep -i tesseract

should give you no output.

Thanks!  I have done this, and the result is:
framework:~/Downloads$ tesseract
bash: /snap/bin/tesseract: No such file or directory

You may have to re-login. And, what is the output of apt --installed list "tesseract*"?

Did this first:
framework:~$ apt --installed list "tesseract*"
Listing... Done
tesseract-ocr-eng/noble,noble,now 1:4.1.0-2 all [installed]
tesseract-ocr-osd/noble,noble,now 1:4.1.0-2 all [installed,automatic]
tesseract-ocr-ukr/noble,noble,now 1:4.1.0-2 all [installed]
tesseract-ocr/noble,now 5.3.4-1build5 amd64 [installed]
will re-login now

Aha! Just restarted and it worked!  Thank you FedKad!
By the bye, is there ever any point in using snap?

Besides snaps being much more up-to-date (like in Firefox and Thunderbird) than apt packages, I don't see any practical point.

@AndrewCorser Accepting and / or upvoting an answer that helped you is an expected action to help other people with similar problem / questions.
